# Render React child component with conditional rendering and one general wrapping html element

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, conditional-rendering

I have a React component:

```
const Options = () => {

  // Option logic
  
  if (isOptionOne) {
    return <OptionOne />;
  }

  if (isOptionTwo) {
    return <OptionTwo />;
  }

  if (isOptionThree) {
    return <OptionThree />;
  }

  return null;
};
```

I render this component inside a parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {

    <ComponentA />
    <span css={styles.container}
      <Options />
    </span>

  };
```

What is a clean approach to move the `<span>` tag to the child component (`<Options />`), since I want to render this html tag only if `<Options />` component does not return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it inside each condition:

```
const Options = () => {

  // Option logic
  
  if (isOptionOne) {
    return (
      <span css={styles.container}>
        <OptionOne />
      </span>
    )
  }

  if (isOptionTwo) {
   return (
      <span css={styles.container}>
        <OptionTwo />
      </span>
    )
  }

  if (isOptionThree) {
     return (
      <span css={styles.container}>
        <OptionThree />
      </span>
    )
  }

  return null;
};
```

There is no need to overthink this. This is clean enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ChoiceComponent = () => {
  let selectedComponent = null;

  if (conditionForOptionA) {
    selectedComponent = <OptionA />;
  } else if (conditionForOptionB) {
    selectedComponent = <OptionB />;
  } else if (conditionForOptionC) {
    selectedComponent = <OptionC />;
  }

  return selectedComponent ? (
    <span css={choiceStyles.wrapper}>{selectedComponent}</span>
  ) : null;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check if Options component returns null or the component. If the component is returned then render, else don't.

You can use Boolean() for checking if it returns null or component.

if it returns false then don't render html tag if it does then render.

The code looks like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const shouldRenderOptions = Boolean(Options({/*pass the props here */});

  return (
    <ComponentA />
    {shouldRenderOptions && (
      <span css={styles.container}>
        <Options />
      </span>
    )}
  );
};
```

Comment: If a component returns null, that does not mean ```<Component />``` will return the same thing. It returns component instance, an object. You can not put that in condition, it is always truthy

Comment: no it doesn't return always truthy if That compoent returns null then it gives false in Boolean(). 
Please use this playground link I have tested. https://playcode.io/1750003 
It works for your problem as you have described.

Comment: Just console log what ```<Options />``` returns. It is an object. Boolean of object returns true

Comment: Please see the code i have updated it's working fine.

Comment: In the question it is mentioned ```I have a React component```, you can not call a component as a function. What if it has a state? What if it does api requests? A component is used with ```React.createElement```, if you are just calling it as a function, that means it is not a component, but function that returns ```ReactElement``` and it cannot use hooks

Comment: Yes , that would be a case. I overthink on this.